# Como obter variável de um form em HTML?

Tags: php, html, session

Eu tenho um ficheiro HTML (html1) para preencher `user` e `pass`, e chamo um ficheiro PHP (php1) para autenticar os valores. Mas preciso do user noutro ficheiro PHP (php2) como faço para chamar o valor de `user` no ficheiro php2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer e criando uma sessão e colocando o `user` nela.

exemplo :

```
session_start();

$_SESSION_['user'] = $user;

// no outro arquivo você chama $_SESSION_['user']
```

outra forma também e incluir o segundo arquivo.

```
include('caminhodoarquivo.php');

// chame $user;
```